# How to use JSObervable in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, observable, jsrender, jsviews

I have my TypeScript project, I have my JSRender and JSViews working but when I try to use JSObservables, it fails.
I understand that this part is not included in "jsrender.d.ts" and I couldn't find how to add it.

Am I taking this the wrong way ? Is there a more complete d.ts file ?

Comment: Where did you get the jsrender.d.ts version you are using?

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply, I've found it on NuGet from VS2015: <package id="jsrender.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="0.1.8" targetFramework="net461" />.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you:

```
 interface JsObserve<T> {
    cdId: string;
    bnd: any;
}

interface JsObserveEventArgs<T> {
    change: string;
    path: string;
    value: T;
    oldValue: T;
    remove: boolean;
}

interface JsObserveEven<T> {
    currentTarget: T;
}

interface JsObservable<T> {

    observeAll<U>(handler: (ev: JsObserveEven<U>, eventArgs: JsObserveEventArgs<U>) => void): void;
    unobserveAll<U>(handler: (ev: JsObserveEven<U>, eventArgs: JsObserveEventArgs<U>) => void): void;

    setProperty<U>(path: string, value: U): void;
    setProperty<U>(path: string, path2: string, value: U): void;
    removeProperty(path: string): void;

    refresh<T>(items: T): void;

    remove<U>(data: U): void;
    remove<U>(index: Number, to: Number): void;
    insert<U>(value: U): void;
    insert<U>(index: number, value: U): void;
    insert<U>(index: number, value: Array<U>): void;
    move(oldIndex?: number, newIndex?: number, numToMove?: number): void;
    data(): T;
}

interface JQueryStatic {
    observable<T>(obj: T): JsObservable<T>;
    observable<T>(obj: T, path: string, handler: (ev: any, eventArgs: any) => any): JsObservable<T>;

    observe<T>(myObjectOrArray: T, handler: (ev: JQueryEventObject, eventArgs: JsObserveEventArgs<T>) => void): JsObserve<T>;
    observe<T>(myObjectOrArray: T, path: string, handler: (ev: JQueryEventObject, eventArgs: JsObserveEventArgs<T>) => void): JsObserve<T>;
    observe<T>(myObjectOrArray: T, path: string, path1: string, handler: (ev: JQueryEventObject, eventArgs: JsObserveEventArgs<T>) => void): JsObserve<T>;
    observe<T>(myObjectOrArray: T, path: string, path1: string, path2: string, handler: (ev: JQueryEventObject, eventArgs: JsObserveEventArgs<T>) => void): JsObserve<T>;

    unobserve<T>(myObjectOrArray: T, handler: (ev: JQueryEventObject, eventArgs: JsObserveEventArgs<T>) => void): JsObserve<T>;
    unobserve<T>(myObjectOrArray: T, path: string, handler: (ev: JQueryEventObject, eventArgs: JsObserveEventArgs<T>) => void): JsObserve<T>;
    unobserve<T>(myObjectOrArray: T, path: string, path1: string, handler: (ev: JQueryEventObject, eventArgs: JsObserveEventArgs<T>) => void): JsObserve<T>;
    unobserve<T>(myObjectOrArray: T, path: string, path1: string, path2: string, handler: (ev: JQueryEventObject, eventArgs: JsObserveEventArgs<T>) => void): JsObserve<T>;
}
```

Should work for this [jsrender](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jsrender/index.d.ts) definitely typed file, but maybe I did not cover all the functionality.

**Update:**

Project must be contain [jquery](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jquery/index.d.ts) definitely typed, because it uses the `JQueryEventObject`.

Comment: Hello, 

Thank you ! Works until now !  Just noticed a 't' is missing on this line: "interface JsObserveEven"

I couldn't make this line work but seems to work without it: /// <reference types="jsrender"/>

:-)

Comment: @ClaudeVernier Thanks, i fix it!